# Angular NVD3 charts: Unable to hide X and Y axes for stacked area chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, axis, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Ran this example from Angular NVD3's 'live edit' area.
http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/

I opened it in Plunkr: [Stacked Area Chart](http://plnkr.co/edit/CIGW0o?p=preview)

As per the documentation,you need to add the following code, to hide the x and y axes.

```
showXAxis: false,
showYAxis: false,
```

You can add it after line number 19(in plunkr -> app.js)

After adding the above code, it doesn't work. The chart shows up and then dissapears.

But the same works for other charts, except for stacked area chart.
[I have tried it on line-chart, filled-line-chart, bar-chart]

Awaiting a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Figured this one out.

Zoom is enabled for this chart (app.js -> line:31)

Rolling the mouse zooms into the chart, and it expects the axis to be enabled (to understand the chart better).

Disabling the axis for a zoomable chart may not make sense, as one would not understand, what portion/section of the chart is showing after you have zoomed in.

Thank you. :-)